# How can fit width of div to content and center parent div?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.main {
  float: left;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img_list {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img_item {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="img_list">
    <div class="img_item">
      <p>＜Hinh 1＞</p>
      <img src="../a/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img_item">
      <p>＜Hinh 2＞</p>
      <img src="../a/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img_item">
      <p>＜Hinh 3＞</p>
      <img src="../a/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img_item">
      <p>＜Hinh 4＞</p>
      <img src="../a/1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is target result:

[image]

How can to center "img_list" as below:
[image]

---

Note: i had edit css of "main":

```
.main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Result:
Zoom = 100%:
[image]

If I zoom out, zoom in , it still align left:
[image]

I want it center as:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally center an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element)

Comment: Can you also include your image assets in the example? Are you trying to achieve a centered layout that wraps the content if it exceeds its parent width?

Comment: Yes, i want it center as last image.

Answer (score 0):

**simply replace this it should work for you**

```
.main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I try change css of main class, result updated in my question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that content moves to left on small screen is because the screen width gets small and therefore the last image gets pushed to the next line.
I have updated my answer.

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img_list {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.img_item {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, i don't want display in one line, i want auto break line, if not enough width and all images can center.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.img_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-warp: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.img_item {
  Width: auto;
  gap: 10px; //if want space add this css
}
```